# Most efficient way to draw rectangle on image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the most preferred and efficient method to draw a rectangle using WPF. I need to draw a rectangle on canvas/bitmap at a specific location with specific dimensions. I have tried out the following.
1.Drawing onto canvas using OnRender using DrawRectangle
2.Drawing onto bitmap using WriteableBitmapExtensions

I also came across StreamGeometry and PathGeometry classes. Didnt give it a try.

I need my application to scale enough to draw 10000s of rectangles in the fastest way possible, Which is the best way of doing my task?
TIA

Comment: Why don't you try using a `StopWatch`?

Comment: `Path` geometry is very powerful. Give it a try. You can actually draw *anything* if you understand it.

Comment: Why don't you just try the different appoaches to see what best fits your needs? This question will very likely only gather opinions.

Comment: I have been instrumenting examples using stopwatch and measuring performance, just wanted to get opinions and advice since I was new to this. In my findings drawing on to canvas performs better than all other options. But am not sure if any short comings are there.

Thanks for all inputs